# Get timing statistics from time sampled data

Tags: anova, variance, sampling

I have measurement data from a device that is sampled every 5 minutes. It's power level data, and I'm looking to get some statistics on it, specifically time to charge/discharge.

To complicate things, I have 2 sets of data and I want to compare performance for the two data sets.

Since the power level samples are taken every 5 minutes, the charge/discharge times will also be, N*5 minutes. Can I do simple mean/standard deviation calculations on this? Or does the 5 minutes sampling time affect how this is done?

Also, what is the best way to compare the 2 sets of data, which both have 5 minute sampling? Is using an ANOVA test appropriate?